# difference between pandas df.query and using dataframe directly

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a question regarding the accuracy of two statements that I believe do the same job but surprisingly, I got different results!

```
(df.query('has_cancer == False')['test_result'] == 'Negative').mean()
```

`> 0.79639570552147243`

And

```
(df[df['has_cancer'] == False].test_result == 'Negative').sum() / df.shape[0]
```

`> 0.71276595744680848`

Why am getting a difference in the results and it's not a small difference!?

Comment: Can you provide a dataset.

Comment: My bet: you have NaNs in the column. What is the output of `df['test_result'].isna().sum()`?

Comment: @ScottBoston You can find the dataset here: https://github.com/ptyadana/Data-Science-and-Machine-Learning-Projects-Dojo/blob/master/Probability%20%26%20Statistics/Pratical%20Statistics/Data/cancer_test_data.csv

Comment: @mozway, there's no nulls, the result for both columns for nulls is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are filtering the dataframe to has_cancer equal to False in the first statement.

Your second statement you are dividing by df.shape[0], which is not filtered.

```
df['has_cancer'].value_counts() shows:

False    2608
True      306
Name: has_cancer, dtype: int64
```

and,

```
(df[df['has_cancer'] == False].test_result == 'Negative').sum()

2077
```

So, 2077/2608 = 0.7963957055214724
and, 2077/(2608+306) = 0.7127659574468085